# Why does keccak256() return bytes32 instead of uint256 in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, hash, keccak, sha3, bytes32

A hashing function outputs an integer that is 256 bits long... so why not store it as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uint256` is usually used for numbers on which you'd like to perform arithmetic operations like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, etc.

A hash is almost never used like that. You almost never want to multiply a hash by `7`. From that perspective it makes sense that it would have a different type.

If you call a hash an integer, you might as well call every piece of data an integer: pictures, strings, pdf documents, hashes, ... all integers because they all consist of bits. Maybe we should use integral data types for all of them.

Comment: I disagree that you would never use arithmetic operations on it, and in that way it is unlike strings. For example, adding the output of 5 hash functions increases the range of outputs and shifts the distribution, which is both useful and not uncommon.